# how to solve ClassNotFoundExceptions : org.apache.commons.beanutils.Converter

Tags: tomcat, struts-1

After deploying a web application i am getting the below error  :

**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.beanutils.Converter**

I am using Apache Tomcat 5.5 and Struts 1.3.8
I have copied the required jars but still facing this problem.i am missing any jars?
please help

thanks in advance

Comment: @thinksteep : i dont have duplicate jars..

Comment: @DaveNewton : i downloaded commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0 and copied its executable jar file in server/lib.but still doesnt work. still am i missing something? please help.thanks

Comment: It's be easier to just get all the jars you need. Consider using maven or equivalent.

Comment: @DaveNewton : thanks Dave... findjar.com is also a good option.

Comment: findjar finds jars, it doesn't *manage* dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You may be missing **BeanUtils Core And Modules**
You will find details [here](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/)
Put `commons-beanutils.jar` in the `WEB-INF/lib`

*Note:* check your project Build path.

Comment: adding commons-beanutils.jar to WEB-INF/lib helped me to reduce the problem thanks a lot..but now error is :java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.apache.commons.digester.RuleSet

Comment: Check in `Tomcat_Install\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib`, if you have `commons-digester.jar` from apache.

Java Doc [here](http://commons.apache.org/digester/commons-digester-1.8/docs/api/) and check your **application** have any one of the jar given [here](http://javacio.us/search?q=org%2Fapache%2Fcommons%2Fdigester%2FRuleSet+more%3Ajar_files&inline=true)

Comment: to remove exception i kept downloading and adding jars to WEB-INF/lib and finally i have reached to following exception :     javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorResources.<init>([Ljava/net/URL;)V..I didnot find this jar to download :( ... Are these problems i am facing because i am using Struts 1.3.8??

Comment: you may find solution [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2301058)